# Excel VBA - Calculate in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

simple problem. I have a String representing a Formula.

Like

```
Dim formula As String
formula = Replace(processFormula(2016, 9000, constants, formulaRow), "##", 9000)
'formula has the value "(1007,27*((9000 - 8820)/10000)+1400)*((9000 - 8820)/10000)"

MsgBox (formula)

'Evaluate(formula) not working sadly
```

Now I want to evaluate it inside VBA and return the result. I don't get Evaluate to work for the calculation.

processFormula is a function generating a formula and it returns a String. So a String is put into the replace function which replaces '##' by a number. Nothing magical here. Regarding to the Debugger formula is a String with the value stated above (it's copied directly from the debugger).

Is there a simple and easy way?

Thanks, I hope it's not a duplicate.

Comment: What is `processFormula`? Is it any function? What output comes from `processFormula`?

Comment: It is a string that is returned. So I put a string into Replace.

Comment: you should replace the comma by a point in 1007,27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace the decimal comma by a decimal point

```
Dim formula As String
formula = replace(Replace(processFormula(2016, 9000, constants, formulaRow), "##", 9000),",",".")
'formula has the value "(1007,27*((9000 - 8820)/10000)+1400)*((9000 - 8820)/10000)"

MsgBox (formula)

Evaluate(formula) 'should work now ;o)
```

Comment: Yes: Evaluate always expects US English formulas

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem:

```
Sub eval()
    MsgBox Evaluate((100 * 20) / 30 * 500)
End Sub
```

[image]

which matches the equivalent cell formula.  Note this is **not** the same as:

```
   (100*20)/(30*500)
```

**EDIT#1:**

This also works:

```
Sub eval2()
    Dim s As String
    s = "((100 * 20) / 30 * 500)"
    MsgBox Evaluate(s)
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is it is a String. I'll change it in my description

Comment: @sascha10000  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I'd put the exact formula into the description. And Iam using evaluate as you are stating. It is not working.

Comment: Yeah I added the relevant part. As I see the problem is not about the string it self.

Answer (score 0):

Use following sub.

```
Sub Calculate()
Dim x As Double
    x = ((100 * 20) / 30 * 500)
    Range("A1") = x
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

Comment: As I stated I have a string. I corrected it in in my question. I don't think that I can assign a string to double even if it's a forumla. Right?